# I know it's an easy one but I'm a bit lost in code. How do I make the timer stop once it hits 00:00?

Tags: javascript, timer

```
if anyone might guide me to create a stopTimer function that works in this scenario I will send all my good thoughts and energy towards them :) thank you in advance!
```

I'm making a hostel rooms management little script, I've made a timer that countdowns from whatever time I tell him to, but I got a bit stuck on the stopTimer part. I've added the "min" id to test it out so I don't have to wait a billion years every time.  I've only uploaded the one minute part of the script so I don't create a mental trauma of how disorganized this code is at the moment.

```
  <div id="circle"> <p class='roomnumber'>1</p> </div>
            <div id="howmanyhours">
                 <ul>
                        <li id="twore"><div><span class="timetwore">2 Ore</span> </div> </li>
                        <br>
                        <li id="three">3 Ore</li>
                        <br>
                        <li id="min">1min Ore</li>
                        <br>
                        <li id="five">5 Ore</li>
                        <br>
                        <li id="day">24 Ore</li>
                </ul>

        </div>
<script>
// making stuff happen ye ye ye yo yo yo ye 

  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
} 




//onemin
var onemin = document.querySelector("#min");
   onemin.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var oneMinutes = 60 * 1,
              display = document.querySelector('#min');
                     startTimer(oneMinutes, display);


})





</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are searching for [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds,
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//onemin
var onemin = document.querySelector("#min");
onemin.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var oneMinutes = 10 * 1, // should be 60 * 1
    display = document.querySelector('#min');
  startTimer(oneMinutes, display);
})
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <p class='roomnumber'>1</p>
</div>
<div id="howmanyhours">
  <ul>
    <li id="twore">
      <div><span class="timetwore">2 Ore</span> </div>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li id="three">3 Ore</li>
    <br>
    <li id="min">1min Ore</li>
    <br>
    <li id="five">5 Ore</li>
    <br>
    <li id="day">24 Ore</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns a handle `intervalID` which can be used to cancel the interval using the `clearInterval` method. E.g.

```js
let i = 0;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(i++);
  if (i === 10)
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

> The returned intervalID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval() to cancel the timeout.
>   [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)